# Javascript Image Trick

Tags: javascript, html, css, slide

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var count = 0;
var images = [
    "http://79.115.69.135:8521/UnderConstruction/Images/deestiny.jpg",
    "http://79.115.69.135:8521/UnderConstruction/Images/dishonored.jpg",
    "http://79.115.69.135:8521/UnderConstruction/Images/fallout4.jpg",
    "http://79.115.69.135:8521/UnderConstruction/Images/fc3.jpg",
    "http://79.115.69.135:8521/UnderConstruction/Images/halo5.jpg",
    "http://79.115.69.135:8521/UnderConstruction/Images/me-som.jpg",
    "http://79.115.69.135:8521/UnderConstruction/Images/rise.jpg",
    "http://79.115.69.135:8521/UnderConstruction/Images/road4.jpg",
    "http://79.115.69.135:8521/UnderConstruction/Images/southpark.jpg",
    "http://79.115.69.135:8521/UnderConstruction/Images/subzero.jpg",
    "http://79.115.69.135:8521/UnderConstruction/Images/tesv.jpg",
    "http://79.115.69.135:8521/UnderConstruction/Images/thief.jpg",
    "http://79.115.69.135:8521/UnderConstruction/Images/watchdogs.jpg",
    "http://79.115.69.135:8521/UnderConstruction/Images/me-sow.jpg",
    "http://79.115.69.135:8521/UnderConstruction/Images/wot.jpg",

];
var image = $(".background");

image.css("background-image", "url(" + (images[count] + ")"))

setInterval(function () {
    image.fadeOut(1500, function () {
        image.css("background-image", "url(" + images[count++] + ")");
        image.fadeIn(1500);
    });
    if (count == images.length) {
        count = 0;
    }
},10000);     });
```

I have this JavaScript code....every time I want to add a new image,I need to write a new line with http://ip.com/folder/folder/img.img...
1.How can i make it to be random...select random images!
2.How to make only 1 line with ip.com...never made a new line when i want to add a image!

[For Dev who are courious](http://79.115.68.191:8521)

Comment: 1. Did you try Google Javascript random number?

Comment: 2. You're looking for the wonders of string concatenation.

Comment: Yes,but i dont know how to use that on files/images.

Comment: You don't know how to do what, exactly? Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the random numbers:

Adapted from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random):

```
function getRandomNumber(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
```

where `max` is `images.length`. You'll get random numbers between 0 and `images.length - 1`.

For the string concatenation:

```
var baseUrl = "http://79.115.69.135:8521/UnderConstruction/Images/"
```

You can remove the long string in each element of the array, keeping only the filenames. Then you can just do something like (also, you had too many parentheses):

```
image.css("background-image", "url(" + baseUrl + images[count] + ")")
```

Edit:

First I define the function

```
var getRandomNumber = function (max) { 
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) 
}
```

Then I use the function to get the first image:

```
var randomNumber = getRandomNumber(images.length) 
image.css("background-image", "url(" + baseUrl + images[randomNumber] + ")")
```

Then I use the function in the setInterval to continuously generate a random number. You could even go so far as to check whether the new number is the same as the old one and do it again so that you don't ever choose the same image twice (but I'll leave you to figure out how to do that).

```
setInterval(function () { 
  image.fadeOut(1500, function () { 
    randomNumber = getRandomNumber(images.length) 
    image.css("background-image", "url(" + baseUrl + images[randomNumber] + ")"); 
    image.fadeIn(1500); 
  });
},10000); });
```

Last edit:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var images = [
    '1.png',
    '2.png',
    '3.png',
    '4.png'
  ]

  var image = $('.background')

  // build the function
  var getRandomNumber = function (max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
  }
  // set a variable to receive a value
  var randomNumber = getRandomNumber(images.length)

  // use the value to index into the array
  image.css('background-image', 'url(' + (images[randomNumber] + ')'))

  setInterval(function () {
    var lastRandomNumber = randomNumber
    // and then do it again, every time
    randomNumber = getRandomNumber(images.length)
    // you could also check whether or not it's the same number and do it over
    while (randomNumber === lastRandomNumber) {
      randomNumber = getRandomNumber(images.length)
    }
    image.fadeOut(1500, function () {
      image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[randomNumber] + ')')
      image.fadeIn(1500)
    })
  }, 10000)
})
```

Comment: I tried to do this (http://prntscr.com/hmmxwu)...but i still have some errors I used my brain to resolve that errors but all time i meet this problem(http://prntscr.com/hmmymd)...i dont know where i need to place that pharanthese :\

Comment: No worries. You need to first define the function, which is what I've done for you. And then, whenever you need a random number, you call the function and save the result into a variable. Which you can then use to index into the `images` array.

Comment: @IonutDaniel Have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope...(http://prntscr.com/hmzrlt) still got some errors.I`m tired of this.I think i will let the code as it was. Also,i tried to change ,,max,, with ,,images.lenght,, or other name,but nothing...

Comment: EDIT...(http://prntscr.com/hmzynu) i did something like this,and now its working,but still not random :))

Comment: @IonutDaniel just updated the answer; it works on my system. good luck.